# Expectation of distinct values

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable defined on the set of integers $\{0,1,\dots\}$.
Let $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of **i.i.d.** random variables of same law as $X$.
Let $N_n$ be the random variable that counts the number of distinct values up to time $n$ that is $N_n=\# \{ X_1,\dots,X_n\}$.

I want to show that $E[N_n]=o(\sqrt n)$, provided $E[X] < + \infty$.

One can show that for all $p \le n : E[N_n] \le p + n\mathbb P(X>p)$ hence by Markov inequality $E[N_n] \le p + \frac np E[X1_{X>p}]$ hence $E[N_n] \le (1+o(1)) \sqrt n$ by taking $p =\sqrt n$.

How to go further ?